# Get movie title from TMDb with Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I'm trying to get a movie title from TMDb API but:

> ErrorException
>
> Trying to access array offset on value of type int

**Controller**

```
$getPopuler = Http::withToken(config('services.tmdb.token')) 
    -> get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular') 
    -> json();

    dump($getPopuler);

    return view('pages.index', [
        'getPopuler' => $getPopuler
    ]);
```

The result of `dump($getPopuler)` gives [this](https://ibb.co/RvnqRYm).

**Blade**

```
@foreach ($getPopuler as $populer)
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{ asset('assets/image/poster01.jpg') }}" alt="Poster-01">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">{{ $populer['title'] }}</h6>
                <i class="fas fa-star"><span class="ml-1">85%</span></i>
                <p class="tahun"><small>Mar 20, 2020</small></p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does your dump of `$getPopular` show?

Comment: https://ibb.co/RvnqRYm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your API call is working, I think you need to access the `results` array of the API response, as per the [documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies).

```
@foreach ($getPopuler['results'] as $populer)
```

Side note: 'populer' is spelled 'popular'.

Comment: can you answer my question at [Next Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949853/get-movie-info-by-title-from-tmdb-with-laravel)